# Doesn't show domain name on browser

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, dns, webserver, url-routing

I am having issue on my Apache web server.

I am doing URL forwarding at domain controller control panel. Say our client typing the domain `example.com` and it will redirect to `123.456.789.10/www` (my webserver fix IP address). Our client browser will then shows `123.456.789.10/www` on their browser instead of showing `example.com`.

Is this anything to do to my Apache setting or how to go about it? It looks weird to show my client the IP address instead of the domain name.

Comment: Why don't you use an A record?

Comment: Do u means configuring DNS A record on domain controller control panel(other party) or at my Windows Server 2003?

Comment: I mean in the domain's DNS registration.  You _need_ to understand how DNS works.

Comment: I am using godaddy. I saw it on DNS Manager - CName.Currently under www it point to @

Comment: Or A Hosts  @ Points to my server IP address? Then remove the URL Forwarding?

Answer (score 3):

You should set an A record in your DNS registration to point the root domain name (`@`) to your IP address.
(and probably a similar A record for the `www` host)

You may need to configure the web server to respond to that hostname.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now I am looking into the configuration of apache server. Coz I have few domain hosts in my apache webserver

Comment: I need to configure Virtual host under Apache configuration file right? Let me know if I am on the right track. THanks!

Comment: Correct​​​​​​​​.  I've never used Apache, so I can't help you there.